Userdata to start and run Jupyter Notebook with Dockerfile
Hello I am trying to start an AWS EC2 ubuntu t2.micro instance using this userdata by creating a dockerfile and running the dockerfile, it works if I ssh into the instance but when I try to run these commands via userdata I am getting an error when trying to access my instance via public IP.
I tried this userdata and I was expecting a jupyter notebook server to pop up once I accessed the instance via public IP
#!/bin/bash

# Update package list and install necessary packages
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip docker.io

# Start Docker service
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker

# Install Jupyter Notebook
pip3 install jupyter

# Generate Jupyter Notebook configuration
jupyter notebook --generate-config

# Create a Dockerfile
cat <<EOF > Dockerfile
# Use the official Python image from the Docker Hub
FROM python:3.9

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install Jupyter Notebook
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir jupyter

# Expose the default Jupyter Notebook port
EXPOSE 80

# Command to run Jupyter Notebook
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=80", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
EOF

# Build the Docker image
docker build -t jupyter .

# Run the Docker container
docker run -d -p 80:80 jupyter

# Optional: Print the URL to access Jupyter Notebook
echo "Jupyter Notebook is running. Access it at http://<your-ec2-public-ip>:80"


Why is this tagged with amazon-ecs? I don't see anything in the question to indicate you are using ECS.

Why run it in docker?

@Paolo that is the way I am doing it, if you have a better way please share
